# How to Push Project (Repo) History to Git (Gitlab Server) After Server is Broken

Tags: git, gitlab, repository

I had a local GitLab server with a project. After few months, the server was broken and the repository was gone. Now, I have a local repository with unpushed files. All the history is available on my local repository though. The new GitLab server is now empty with no project.

How can I push all my local machine repository history (following with the unpushed files) to the new GitLab server? What steps should I do to create the repository just like the way it was before? There are other developers that we were working on this repo, however, they don't have any unpushed files. My local machine has the most updated state of the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I did and it worked:

1. Create a new project on GitLab (with the same group and name as before)
2. Set the new GitLab Name and Email (if different from before):

```
    $ git config --global user.name "Name"
    $ git config --global user.email email@example.com
```

3. Commit any uncommitted changes on Git (`git commit`).
4. Set the new GitLab project URL to Git (if changed from before):

```
    $ git remote set-url origin [URL]
```

4. Use commands below to push all the history tree to the new project:

```
    $ git push -u origin --all
    $ git push -u origin --tags
```

5. You can finally check the history tree on the GitLab Web to make sure everything is done correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do the following steps to get the new repo

1. Just open terminal and write the command

```
git init
```

2. update remote url

```
git remote set-url origin <new-GitLab-repo-URL>
```

3. push you local branch to new origin

```
git push -u origin --all
```

Comment: You don't need to run `git init` for a repo that was already initialized.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with GitLab, but with GitHub it should be as simple as committing the changes and force pushing to the remote repository (make sure you make a copy of the uncommitted directory in case of any unexpected failures):

```
$ git push <remotename> <branchname> --force
```

ex.

```
$ git push origin main --force
```

Without force pushing, git will ask you to rebase to the remote version, which is what you don't want.

If this does not work, worst case scenario you can still create a new GitLab server and push files there, which is probably not a desirable solution.